# Concurrent Download Ends Immediately

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell, and wrote the following program as an exercise.

`Main.hs`

```
module Main (main) where

import ParallelDownloader

import System.IO (hPutStrLn,stderr)
import GHC.IO.Encoding (setLocaleEncoding, utf8)
import System.Environment (getArgs)


main :: IO ()
main = do
    setLocaleEncoding utf8
    args <- getArgs
    case args of
        [inputFile] -> do
            fileContents <- readFile inputFile
            retrieveUrls 4 (lines fileContents)
        _ -> hPutStrLn stderr "Input File Not Specified"
```

`ParallelDownloader.hs`

```
module ParallelDownloader where
import System.IO
import Network.HTTP
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Monad(forM_)

fetchUrl url = simpleHTTP (getRequest url) >>= getResponseBody

retrieve url savePath = do
    responseData <- fetchUrl url
    writeFile savePath responseData

getPath :: String -> String
getPath = reverse . takeWhile (/= '/') . reverse

workerThread q = do
    url <- readChan q
    if url == "" then
        return ()
    else do
        retrieve url (getPath url)
        workerThread q

retrieveUrls :: Int -> [String] -> IO ()
retrieveUrls numThread urls  = do
    que <- newChan
    waitq <- newChan
    forM_ urls $ \u -> writeChan que u
    forM_ [1..numThread] $ \_ -> writeChan que ""
    forM_ [1..numThread] $ \_ -> forkFinally (workerThread que) (\_ -> writeChan waitq ())
    forM_ [1..numThread] $ \_ -> readChan waitq
```

However, when I run the program, it ends immediately without doing anything? How can I make this work?

Comment: It works for me. What do you have in the input file you're giving it? Do all of the URLs have a filename after the last `/`?

Comment: Also, do you actually have a real use for concurrency, or are you just trying to learn how to use it? If the former, have you considered just using `mapConcurrently_`?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I have 69 urls, that all start with `https://` and have a path component. I was trying to control maximum number of concurrent file downloads with this. I am not sure how `mapConcurrently_`  works.

Comment: What happens if you call `retrieveUrls` directly from GHCi? What about just `retrieve`?

Comment: See [Can Haskell's Control.Concurrent.Async.mapConcurrently have a limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18896103/7509065) to put a limit on.

Comment: If I call retrieve from ghci I get `Exception: user error (https not supported)` error. I wonder why I don't see anything when I run the executable :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resolving Network.HTTP 'user error (https not supported)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21296606/resolving-network-http-user-error-https-not-supported)

Comment: Ah, that's the key! I was testing with insecure HTTP. And as for why you don't see it, it's being swallowed by the parallelization/forking.

Comment: ICYMI, Simon Marlow's [_Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell_](https://simonmar.github.io/pages/pcph.html) is a great free resource on... that thing you're doing.

Answer (score 3):

There's two things going on here:

1. The HTTP library only supports insecure HTTP, not HTTPS. [Resolving Network.HTTP 'user error (https not supported)'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21296606/7509065) explains what you can do about that. Anyway, if you try to use HTTPS anyway, it throws an exception in IO.
2. `forkFinally` takes any exceptions thrown inside itself and returns them in the `Left` side of an `Either`. However, your code that takes the `Either` is just `(\_ -> writeChan waitq ())`, so you're discarding the exception and carrying on as if it succeeded. This explains why you couldn't see what was going wrong.